# NodeJS Puppeteer Block Popups

Tags: node.js, iframe, arguments, puppeteer

Essentially I am just trying to fill out some input fields on a shopify site, however halfway through that I get an iframe popup from the site with some sort of sale which obviously causes the input typing to fail.

I was curious if there was any argument I could add to the browser that would block popups? I have tried

```
--enable-popup-blocking
```

But that doesn't seem to work.

Failing that is there any other way to close the popup?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: A scrappy workaround is to add an ```if (popup != null){ click to exit the popup, delete what you have in the input field, reenter input and then move on)"``` after your type finishes. Or if it always shows up, then just wait for it and then exit it before inputting. I know it's not what you're looking for but it'll get the job done.

Answer (score 0):

See https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/v0.12.0/docs/api.md#class-dialog and https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/v0.12.0/docs/api.md#event-dialog

if the popup is a custom HTML, then you have to write your own logic to delete the popup from DOM